# Powershell - Find & Replace Dates

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a bit of assistance here. I currently have a Powershell script which adjusts the dates within a file. I'm looking to stop myself having to manually adjust these dates every time. What I need is to replace the date two days ago, with the date from yesterday.

I believe that I'd have to use `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` and `(Get-Date).AddDays(-2)` but I'm not exactly sure how I'd script this in!

What I currently have:

```
echo "Adjusting Import Dates"

(Get-Content D:\Temp\Example.txt).replace('20180917', '20180918') | Set-Content  D:\Temp\Example.txt
```

Comment: Can you please include some sample input and expected output. Is this a file of just dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
$twodaysago = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
(Get-Content D:\Temp\Example.txt).replace($twodaysago, $yesterday) | Set-Content D:\Temp\Example.txt
```

You just introduce variables for the two dates and format them to the required date format.
There is probably some other way of replacing in files, but the above should work.